# Need help understanding measurability of a given set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Fix some probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$, and let $\mathscr{A}\subset\mathscr{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Suppose that $g,h:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are two $\mathbb{P}$-integrable and $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions.

I need help understanding why $\{h>g\}\in\mathscr{A}$? I understand that since $g$ and $h$ both are $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, it holds that for all $B\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$:
\begin{equation}
h^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{A},\quad g^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{A}.
\end{equation}
However, I can't seem to make the connection as to why $\{h>g\}\in\mathscr{A}$ also holds true.

Comment: $\{h>g\}=\cup_{r \in \mathbb Q} [(h>r)\cap (g<r)]$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not familiar with this identity, could you elaborate? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{h>g\}=\{h-g>0\}\in\mathscr{A}$ because if $h$ and $g$ are $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, then the difference $h-g$ is also $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.

To see this, note that for all $t\in\mathbb R$, $h-g< t\iff h< t+g \iff h < q < t+g$ for some rational $q$. So
$$\{h-g<t\} = \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\{h < q < t+g\} = \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\{h < q\}\cap\{ g>q-t\} $$
Hence $\{h-g<t\}\in\mathscr A$ as a countable union of elements of $\mathscr A$, and therefore $h-g$ is $\mathscr A$-measurable.